# Did any part of the Netherlands ever use this flag?

Tags: europe, identification, flags, netherlands, dutch-empire

Was there ever any part of the Netherlands which had this flag?

[image]
<sup>[Guilherme Paula](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Guilherme_Paula) - [Public Domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_the_Secretary_of_Defence_of_the_Netherlands.svg)</sup>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dutch_flags#Military_and_naval_flags), this is the naval flag of the Netherlands' Secretary of Defense.

This flag would be flown on a ship that the Dutch Secretary of Defense is using as a headquarters (also referred to as a *flagship*). This type of flag is known as a [rank flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maritime_flag#Rank_flags).

Comment: Cool! Learned something today